# data.table | .SD lapply multiple columns in `...`-Argument

Tags: r, data.table

How can i use a fixed specific column the `...` argument of `lapply(.SD, FUN, ...)`

**Example**

```
DT <- data.table(id_column = rnorm(10),
                 x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
measure_col = paste0("x",1:3)

DT[,lapply(.SD, cov, y=id_column), .SDcols = measure_col]
```

Results in

```
Error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'id_column' not found
```

A possible workaround would be

```
DT[,lapply(.SD, cov, y = DT[,id_column]), .SDcols = measure_col]
          x1         x2        x3
1: 0.1703253 -0.2831533 0.3387133
```

Is there a better way of doing it? Without referencing to *y* by `y=DT[,id_column]`

Comment: This is a bug - [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495), which we haven't fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is solved now with [this recent commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/68091d851d400b4d768f3c41c0210da76945c12b), we can now do this just fine:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
DT <- data.table(id_column = rnorm(10), x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
measure_col = paste0("x",1:3)    
DT[,lapply(.SD, cov, y=id_column), .SDcols = measure_col]
#             x1        x2         x3
# 1: -0.03137294 0.1903654 -0.1493648
```