# Pass data.table column into function when using .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use the `DT[, lapply(.SD, func), by=group, .SDcols=cols]` syntax in a `data.table`, but I would like to pass a column of `DT` to `func()`. Is there a way to get this to work? For example,

```
indexfunc <- function(col, indexcol, indexvalue)
  col/col[indexcol==indexvalue]

DT <- data.table(group=c('A','A','B','B'), indexkey=c(1,2,1,2), value=1:4)

# Works
DT[, indexfunc(value, indexkey, 2), by=group]

# Fails, Error in indexfunc(value, indexkey, 2) : object 'indexkey' not found
DT[, lapply(.SD, indexfunc, indexkey, 2), by=group, .SDcols=c("value")]
```

Comment: Seems like this may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152199/r-data-table-using-lapply-on-functions-defined-outside

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495

Comment: Dupe of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755518/data-table-sd-lapply-multiple-columns-in-argument Don't know if it's worth marking as such.

Answer (score 3):

I think the strategy here necessarily entails bad programming, but

```
DT[,lapply(
  .SD[,"value"], 
  indexfunc,indexcol= indexkey,indexvalue= 2
), by=group]
```

gives the output

```
   group value
1:     A  0.50
2:     A  1.00
3:     B  0.75
4:     B  1.00
```

The approach in the OP didn't work because `.SDcols` restricts the set of columns available in `j` of `DT[i,j]`. I think the arguments to the function used in `lapply` must also be named.

Comment: this is a great workaround until the bug is resolved